# How can I remove the built in delay on showing flex title window?

Tags: apache-flex, components

The flex title window component is nice and all, but before it shows up it insists on blurring out the background of your window if it's set to modal.  What if I want it to just show up immediately or at least speed it up so that the user doesn't have to wait around to enter data. Am I going to have to build a custom component based on TitleWindow to get this or not have it be modal? If I were to do that could I extend current TitleWindow or just copy out the source directly?

Comment: How are you creating the title window?  Are you using popup manager to do it?  The blur normally occurs when you set the 'modal' flag when creating a popup.  If you remove that, the blur won't occur.

Comment: That is good to know!  I want it to be modal, though...

Answer (score 4):

Play with Application styles, such as `modalTransparencyDuration`.
Yes, you can apply those in the CSS:

```
global {
    modalTransparencyBlur:      2;
    modalTransparency:      0.8;
    modalTransparencyColor:     #000000;
    modalTransparencyDuration:  500;
}
```

Comment: where are these settings? i checked in the application xml and in the suggested properties of the TitleWindow and application itself and I don't see that option. do i have to apply it via css?

Comment: yes. http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/12/globally-setting-modal-styles-in-a-flex-application/

Answer (score 0):

In your PopupManager set the modal to false.This will allow the user to interact with other popups.

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(titleWindow, this, false);
```

Comment: the tricky thing is I do want it to be modal.. i want only that window to be active until it's dismissed